# C# Discord get entire command message, not remainder

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am trying to get the entire command when a user executes a query.

For example, if a user types ".dog", I want my string message to equal ".dog".

Here is some example code:

```
    [Command("dog")]
    [Alias("cat")]
    public async Task GetAnimal(string message)
```

The intent of this is that sometimes when a user executes the command "dog" it will occasionally return a cat, and vice versa. So I need the original command to key off of.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Context.Message` Is the message that invoked the command. You can use `Context.Message.Content` to get the string input by the user.